# can't get hash value from hashref

Tags: perl, hash, hashref

I'm storing a hash references from a threads to a shared @stories variable, and then can't access them.

```
    my @stories : shared= ();

    sub blah {
    my %stories : shared=();
    <some code>
      if ($type=~/comment/) {
          $stories{"$id"}="$text";
          $stories{"$id"}{type}="$type";
          lock @stories;
          push @stories, \%stories;
      }  
    }
```

`#    @stories is a list of hash references which are shared from the threads;`

```
           foreach my $story (@stories) {
                my %st=%{$story};
                print keys %st;        # <- printed "8462529653954"
                print Dumper %st;      # <- OK
                my $st_id = keys %st;
                print $st_id;          # <- printed "1"
                print $st{$st_id};     # <- printed "1/8"
           }
```

print keys %st works as expected but when i set in to a variable and print, it returns "1".

Could you please advice what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? `$st_id = keys %st` is the same as `$st_id = scalar(keys %st)`, meaning set `$st_id` to the number of keys in the hash `%st`.

Comment: I expect $st_id will be a key. i.e. 8462529653954.

Comment: Are you aware that `my %st=%{$story}` is making a copy of the hash?  Any change you make to `%st` are not reflected in the original hashref.

Comment: yes. At first I tried the same with $story, but when I sow the same thing I just tried this way :). 
I need to get values from the $story hash reference and then copy them to another hash.

Comment: I expect that print $st_id; # will be 8462529653954
and print $st{$st_id}; # will be "some text"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scalar context, `keys %st` returns the number of elements in the hash `%st`.

```
%st = ("8462529653954" => "foo");
$st_id = keys %st;

print keys %st;             #  "8462529653954"
print scalar(keys %st);     #  "1"
print $st_id;               #  "1"
```

To extract a single key out of `%st`, make an assignment from `keys %st` in list context.

```
my ($st_id) = keys %st;     #  like @x=keys %st; $st_id=$x[0]
print $st_id;               #  "8462529653954"
```

Comment: That works, Thank you.
But actually I don understand why keys %st is a list?

Comment: @TigranKhachikyan, because a hash normally has more than 1 key.

Comment: And be aware that if `%st` has multiple keys, which one you get is undefined.  You'll always get the same key until the hash is modified, at which point another key could become "first".